# How to store user login information for Desktop App Integrated with Google Drive SDK

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Given the following code example, which integrate a Java desktop app with Google Drive.

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

I was wondering, how possible can we store user login information in **correct and secure way**, so that he need not to type his username and password again and again.

I realize [official Google Drive for Windows](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive/index.html) only requires us to login once. I was wondering, how do they do that? How do they store user login information securely in local disk?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to store "login information" is to store a refresh token and an access token. You will ask the user to authorize once, using something like a "Setup Wizard". Once you have those credentials, you can store them and use them in the future.

Comment: What if the intruder obtains those token? Possible for them to use the token to login through another machine?